# Data type mismatch in criteria expression c# using access datatype auto number

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-4.0, ms-access-2013

I am using Access and my field userId's datatype is autonumber.
I'm getting a data type mismatch error and I'm not sure why. Here is my code.

```
try 
    { 
        con.Open(); 
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); 
        cmd.Connection = con; 
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from userdetail where userId='" + textBox1.Text + "'"; 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        con.Close(); 
    } 
catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex); 
    }
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons to always use SQL parameters

Comment: do now what should i do any idea coz i m going for this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the id as a *number*:

```
cmd.CommandText = "delete from userdetail where userId = " + textBox1.Text + "";
```

Comment: how plzz tell me i cant understand what you said

Comment: A number must not be wrapped in single-quotes.